# python class method prints address of variable instead of its value

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm trying to write a circular linked list with only 2 methods, push() and show(). but the show() method prints addresses instead of data

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data 
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

class Circular_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node(None)
        self.tail = Node(None)
        self.head.next = self.tail
        self.head.prev = self.tail
        self.tail.next = self.head
        self.tail.prev = self.head

    def push(self, data):
        node = Node(data)

        if self.head.data is None:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
            node.next = self.head
            node.prev = self.tail
            self.tail = node
            self.head.prev = self.tail
            
    def show(self):
        i = self.head
        for temp in range(4):
            print(i.data, end=' ')
            i = i.next
            temp += 1
n1 = Node(1)
n2 = Node(2)
n3 = Node(3)
list = Circular_list()
list.push(n1)
list.push(n2)
list.push(n3)
list.show()
```

the output is `<__main__.Node object at 0x000002A78EDD3FD0> <__main__.Node object at 0x000002A78EDD3F70> <__main__.Node object at 0x000002A78EDD3E80>`
but it's supposed to print `1 2 3`

p.s: note that I originally wrote show() method with infinite while loop and it works just fine in terms of getting from tail to head. so i suppose it's an OK circular linked-list. but unfortunately i can't get the node's data

Comment: Should be: `print(i.data.data, end=' ')`

Comment: You're creating Node objects with data = 1, 2, 3 and then, during your list.push(), you're creating Node objects with data = n1, n2, n3.

Comment: You pass a node to `push`. Then `push` puts that node in a new node. So your node's `data` is another node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `push` method, you do:

```
def push(self, data):
    node = Node(data)
```

So it looks like it accepts data (list elements, `int` in this example), and creates nodes to add to the list.  However, when you call  this method, you are passing `Node` objects:

```
n1 = Node(1)
...
list.push(n1)
```

So in the `push` method, you establish `node` to be be a `Node` with `data` = `Node(1)`.  So the data printed is of type `Node`, and since there is no defined `str` representation, you get the output you see.

You could a) call `push` on the data you want to add or b) change the method so that it expects a `Node`.
a)

```
# n1 = Node(1)
# n2 = Node(2)
# n3 = Node(3)
list = Circular_list()
list.push(1)          # change here
list.push(2)          # change here
list.push(3)          # change here
list.show()
```

Or b):

```
def push(self, node):          # change here
    # node = Node(data)
```

Both giving output:

```
1 2 3 1
```